# JS IOS Safari - open new Tab on Go button

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari, form-submit

Story:

1. User opens a Web page in IOS Safari
2. User clicks a Go button making a Submit of the Form

Expectations:

1. Redirect to google.com should happen in the current Tab. Focus stays on this Tab.
2. Form Submit should happen in the new Tab.

How to bring expectations into Live? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. Hint: show effort and CODE

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a suitable duplicate so

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      window.focus();
      location="https://google.com";
    },500); // delay
  }
}
```

using

```
<form target="_blank" action="somepage.html" id="form1">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```